# Entity Framework - Empty Lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, identity, identityserver4

Helloes,

I'm using Identity Server 4 and I'm having some issues with Entity Framework.

I'm trying to make a custom CRUD for Clients. 
When trying to get a single client information, I'm trying to get several Lists using Entity Framework (default IS4 implementation) but these Lists are returned empty for some reason...

[here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples) you can use the Quickstart 8 - 8_EntityFrameworkStorage - and try to access a Client to get his properties.

Here is my current code

Db Context

```
namespace IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts
{
    public class ConfigurationDbContext : DbContext, IConfigurationDbContext, IDisposable
    {
        public ConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions);

        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResources { get; set; }

        public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Client Entity

```
namespace IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities
{
    public class Client
    {
        public Client();

        public bool AllowOfflineAccess { get; set; }
        public List<ClientScope> AllowedScopes { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Custom Service, where I am trying to get the

```
clnt.AllowedScopes
```

but is empty...

```
namespace IdentityServer.Services
{
    public class ClientService
    {
        private readonly ConfigurationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ClientService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ConfigurationDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ClientService>();
            _context = context;
        }

        //...
        public ClientViewModel GetClientViewModel(int clientId)
        {
            var clnt = _context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == clientId);
            //todo :: return also the lists (they are coming empty)

            var vm = new ClientViewModel();

            if (clnt == null) return vm;

            vm = new ClientViewModel()
            {
                Id = clnt.Id,
                ClientName = clnt.ClientName,
                ClientId = clnt.ClientId,
                AllowedGrantTypes = clnt.AllowedGrantTypes,
                ClientSecrets = clnt.ClientSecrets,
                RedirectUris = clnt.RedirectUris,
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = clnt.PostLogoutRedirectUris,
                AllowedScopes = clnt.AllowedScopes,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = clnt.AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser,
                AllowOfflineAccess = clnt.AllowOfflineAccess,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = clnt.AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = clnt.AlwaysSendClientClaims,
                PrefixClientClaims = clnt.PrefixClientClaims,
                RequireConsent = clnt.RequireConsent
            };
            return vm;
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

I'm getting the correct Client, it has Scopes (I can check it on the database and use it for the IS authentication flow) but the List is empty...

Any thoughts on this?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using EF Core? If yes, you need to eager load related collections (using `Include` / `ThenInclude`). See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this to

```
var clnt = _context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == clientId);`
```

This

```
var clnt = _context.Clients.Include(x => x.AllowedScopes)
               .Include(x => x.OtherNavigationProperty)
               .Include(....)
               .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == clientId);
```

See [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/db8e5320e30dff65f92d89698545f5220607276f/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Stores/ClientStore.cs#L30-L41) for how `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` does it.

Comment: works like a charm! did not know had to use "Include" for loading of dependencies. Thank you, kind sir!